# D7 Why I cannot just copy a template file from a module to my custom theme to override it?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the [TimeField](http://drupal.org/project/timefield) module with a custom theme (a subtheme of the Bootstrap theme) and I want to change how the output is rendered.

There's a `timefield.tpl.php` file located at

> sites/all/modules/timefield/theme/timefield.tpl.php

which I want to modify copying it to

> sites/all/themes/my_theme/templates/

but when I do so the copy is ignored and the original file is loaded instead.

I'm a Drupal newbie but I like to learn, so any advice or link to a resource to understand where the problem lay is fine.

Comment: clear cache for site

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create tpl file for field field--field-name.tpl.php. place it to your theme.

> if Field name is: **field_page_photos**
>   then File name will: **field--field-page-photos.tpl.php**

copy `sites/all/modules/timefield/theme/timefield.tpl.php` code to above tpl file.
make changes and clear cache.

Comment: Cheered too soon... the new template loads OK, but there is a $time variable that is no longer recognized. Any advice?

Comment: create an issue at drupal.org